# One element on other element, and padding beyond div Html, Css

Tags: html, css, styles

```css
main p, main h2, main h3, main h4 {
  width: 268px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 268px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.orange-button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h4>
    Zapraszam!
    </h4>
    <div class="center">
      <a class="orange-button" href="#">
      Przejdź do strony głównej!
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in this snippet padding of `button` goes beyond `div` `.center`

Plus his border goes onto above `h4` element.

I don't know exactly what happened here and what is going on.

This border around `button` shouldn't go beyond `.center` div and especially shouldn't go onto `h4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` in your `orange-button` css

```css
main p, main h2, main h3, main h4 {
  width: 268px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 268px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.orange-button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h4> Zapraszam!</h4>
    <div class="center">
      <a class="orange-button" href="#">
        Przejdź do strony głównej!
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you added padding in button so that it was overlap on title and if you not want to display inline-block in a tag just added `margin-bottom` in `h4`

Answer (score 1):

Only one change in your css,

Please add just `display: block;` css in your `.orange-button` class. Nothing else you need to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
main p, main h2, main h3, main h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.orange-button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h4>
    Zapraszam!
    </h4>
    <div class="center">
      <a class="orange-button" href="#">
        Przejdź do strony głównej!
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you want?